# strange writeline(DateTime results)

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

Here is a little question I hope you guys can help me with.

```
Console.Write("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} " + customerdetails[i].CustomerNo,
    customerdetails[i].surname,
    customerdetails[i].forname,
    customerdetails[i].street,
    customerdetails[i].town,
    customerdetails[i].DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

This little thing actually works and produces everything correctly but after it pops out some strange things which kind of look like some binary code example:

100 Name Surname 123 Street Town 11/11/1111 //correct

```
    01-01-0001 0
    01-01-0001 0
    01-01-0001 0 //What is this? How to get rid of it
    01-01-0001 0
```

This is quite obviously only part of the code and I think there is problem somwhere in here but if If you guys need more code just say so.

Comment: That's the default value (and minimum) of `DateTime`.

Comment: By "this" do you mean the sole `0`? That would be your `customerdetails[i].CustomerNo`.

Comment: `"{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} " + customerdetails[i].CustomerNo` - you are mixing string concatenation and format strings here, why?

Comment: Allright... that makes sense.. Did not think of it, is there a way to set it so it won't show default value? Only the ones I input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final `0` is the `CustomerNo` because your format string is:

```
"{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} " + customerdetails[i].CustomerNo
```

Which becomes:

```
"{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} 0"
```

At this point you supplant the date at position `{4}` but the final 0 still remains there.

To get rid of it replace the `+` with a `,` and replace the format string with:

```
"{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}"
```

Now the `CustomerNo` will be in first position.

To replace the default `DateTime` value do this:

```
string dob;

if (customerdetails[i].DOB == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    dob = "(unknown)"; // or whatever
}
else
{
    dob = customerdetails[i].DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Now use `dob` as an argument of the `Console.Write()`.

Comment: And then the zero would still show up, because it's simply the value of `CustomNo`, or wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes but in the first column, not the last after the datetime, which confused the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you created an array of `customerdetails` instances but only initialized the 1st index instance. Assuming your code:

```
Console.Write("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} " + customerdetails[i].CustomerNo,
    customerdetails[i].surname,
    customerdetails[i].forname,
    customerdetails[i].street,
    customerdetails[i].town,
    customerdetails[i].DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

is in a for-loop, therefore you get value for `customerdetails[0]` and the rest in the list are just showing their default values.

`01-01-0001` for DateTime

`0` for integer

`string.Empty` for string

To get rid of the unwanted values, just remove those uninitialized instances from the list of array.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to set [the DateTime] so it won't show default value? Only the ones I input?

There's no difference between a default DateTime and one set by code. If you want to represent "no date", use a nullable DateTime expressed as `DateTime?`.

Comment: I input all customer details through something like this Console.Write("\n\t\t\tEnter the Customer Surname: ");
customerdetails[x].surname = Console.ReadLine();    And now the max customer is only 5 so the default so there is not too much of the default date but I would like to change it to something higher like 30. So i guess my issue is how could i print out all of the customerdetails that have been manually filled without using every space in an array.